# What is UITabBarItem *item = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]; in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am not familiar with objective-c, how to translate `[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]` into swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift:

```
  //[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]

  self.tabBar.items[1] //tabBar.items[1]
```

Comment: The "self" in Swift is in most cases redundant though.